# Describe the Riemann surface:

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, exponential-function, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

$$W = \sqrt{1-z^2}$$

I would like hints only.

Using @Dr.MV's hint, I get two factors: the first is

$$\sqrt{(x-1)+y^2}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}$$, which, when we let theta range from 0 to 2$\pi$, describes a semi-circular arc in quadrant I, centered at (1,0).

Similarly, the second factor $$\sqrt{(x-(-1))+y^2}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}$$ describes a semi-circular arc in quadrant II, centered at (-1,0), when we let $\phi$ range from 0 to 2$\pi$.

However, these two factors are to be multiplied:

If I multiply the factors, then the resulting argument is $e^{i(\frac{\theta + \phi}{2} )}$, which, when we let both theta and phi range from 0 to 2pi, describes a semi-circular arc that runs through quadrant I and quadrant II - starting at (1,0), and ending at (-1,0)

Where can I go from here?

Thanks,

Comment: Often a "description" consists of fixing a branch of square root, finding a dense open set $U$ of the complex plane on which $\sqrt{1 - z^{2}}$ is analytic, taking two copies of $U$, and describing how $\sqrt{1 - z^{2}}$ on one copy of $U$ is glued to $-\sqrt{1 - z^{2}}$ on the other copy of $U$. Looking at expressions for the square roots in terms of real and imaginary parts may not be the best approach. Were you given information about what constitutes a "description" for your purposes?

Comment: Hi @AndrewD.Hwang, unfortunately, the question is simply, "Describe the Riemann surface of w = $\sqrt{1-z^2}$."  So, say I choose the principal branch of square root (and for z^2), then the function w should be analytic away from the negative real axis, I think.  Using a computational approach as I did (above), I am seeing a semi-circular arc.  But in looking at the two factors, I notice that the radius of this arc can go to infinity.  So, perhaps the Riemann surface is just the area *outside* of the upper unit disk - on the upper half-plane.

Comment: What do you think, @AndrewD.Hwang?  The stuff regarding gluing I have not learned before, but it's definitely possible that that is what the question is really asking...

Comment: Also, writing $\sqrt{1-z^2}$, using the complex definitions that involve the exponential and complex logarithms, I see that at z=-1 and at z=1, we get a (real) log(0), which is undefined.  These I think are the two branch points that Dr.MV is referring to, @AndrewD.Hwang.

Comment: actually, perhaps the Riemann surface is just the complement of the unit disk, @AndrewD.Hwang ...

Comment: Just saw your comments. Looks like you've worked things out, but the bottom line is, this particular Riemann surface can be represented as two copies of a slit plane, "cross-joined" along the slits (the "top" edge of a slit in one copy glued to the "bottom" edge in the other copy). There are multiple ways to achieve the construction. If you cut along the real axis from the branch points to infinity, the picture looks like [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135819/what-is-a-branched-riemann-surface-with-cuts/136184#136184).

Comment: I did, Professor Hwang - it was very exciting and well worth the whole day of thinking :-)  Can I just ask you one more question, if you don't mind?  Does the cross-joining and gluing create a surface that's almost...spherical?  So that the surface gotten from two copies of the slit plane is actually a compact surface (closed and bounded).  Also, this is topology stuff that I know only vaguely about.  Is the rule this:  one can bend, fold, and glue objects that can be studied - but one is not allowed to *cut* and then glue the object to create something new to be studied?Thanks, @andrewdhwang

Comment: Yes, this Riemann surface is complex-analytically equivalent to a sphere. :) More generally, if $p$ is a polynomial of degree $2g + 1$ or $2g + 2$, the Riemann surface $w^{2} = p(z)$ has genus $g$. (Not all Riemann surfaces have this form, however.) "Topology" is the study of "invariants" of continuous, bijective maps having continuous inverse. Loosely, it's all right to cut and deform so long as you "re-glue all the cuts the way they were". For example, it's "allowed" to cut a torus along a circle to get a cylinder, twist through a full turn like a barber pole, then re-glue the ends.

Comment: Ah, that's so cool :-)  -- thanks so much, Professor Hwang!!  Have a great night, @AndrewD.Hwang!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$W=(1-z)^{1/2}(1+z)^{1/2}$$

has branch points at both $z=1$ and $z=-1$.  Now, you can write $z-1=\rho e^{i\phi}$ and $z+1=re^{i\theta}$.  You will find that one suitable branch cut is from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$.

SPOILER ALERT
SCROLL OVER THE SHADED AREA TO REVEAL ANSWER

> First, for both the branch point at $(-1,0)$ and at $(1,0)$, cut the plane along the negative real axis.  Then, let $z+1=re^{i\theta}$ ($z-1=\rho e^{i\phi}$) for $-\pi<\phi<\pi$ and $-\pi<\theta<\pi$. Now, let's see if $W$ is single valued for points just above and just below the branch cut for $z+1$.  For points just  above (below) that branch cut, $\theta =\pi$ ($\theta =-\pi$) and $\phi =\pi$ ($\phi=-\pi$).  Thus, $\arg(W)$ is $\pi$ ($-\pi$) and $W=-(r\rho)^{1/2}$ is single valued.  Now, let's see if $W$ is single valued for points just above and just below the line segment $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$.  For points just  above (below) that segment, $\theta =0$ ($\theta =0$) and $\phi =\pi$ ($\phi=-\pi$).  Thus, $\arg(W)$ is $\pi/2$ ($-\pi/2$) and $W=\pm i (r\rho)^{1/2}$ is multi-valued.  Thus, the effective branch cut is the segment $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$ and $W$ is analytic in the plane less this branch cut.

Comment: Hi @Dr.MV!  I just edited my post to show my work, so far.  What do you think?  I think I know the shape of the surface of each individual factor, but not the product of the factors...

Comment: I think the product gives a semi-circular arc over quadrants I and II, starting from (1,0) and ending at (-1,0).  Am I on the right track, @Dr.MV?  Thanks,

Comment: Is the surface...the complement of the unit disk?

Comment: @LebronJames I don't think that you're heading in the right direction.  Given the HINT, we notice, for example that if you cut the plane for the branch point at $z=-1$ along the negative real axis, and cut the plane for the branch point at $z=+1$ along the positive real axis, that the effective branch cut is the line segment that goes from $(-1,0)$ to $(1,0)$.  So, $W$ is analytic in the plane less that line segment.  See if you can convince yourself of that.

Comment: Before I read the spoiler solution, @Dr.MV, I want to take one more chance at it:  pick one branch of W, where the branch cut is everything on the negative real axis, starting at the branch point -1.  Call this branch of W "f(z)".  Another branch is gotten by making the branch cut along the positive real axis, starting from +1.  Call this branch of W "g(z)".  The f(z) is an analytic continuation of g(z) onto the positive real axis, starting at z=+1, while g(z) is an analytic continuation of f(z) onto the negative real axis, starting from -1.  f(z) = g(z) everywhere else on the plane.

Comment: I'm not sure whether analytic continuation is the key argument to make in this problem...

Comment: $W$ has two branch points and thus two cuts.  We can cut the plane however we choose.  If we judiciously select the branch cuts to overlap, then the result is an "effective" cut only along that segment for which they don't overlap.

Comment: Hi Dr.MV - I finally understand it now!! :-).

Comment: Can I ask just another question regarding this problem, @dr.mv?  How did you pick your branch points?  Do you notice them right away?  Because the function w= z^2 - 1 has branch points at i and -i, and that doesn't seem obvious to recognize.  Is there an algorithm to compute the branch points? (I think *all* the points on the branch cut satisfy the definition of branch point, though.)

Comment: Hi dr.mv - I should really ask you this too:  is all of this, in your opinion, enough of a "description" of the Riemann surface?  I would think so - the branch points and the *choice* of  overlapping branch cuts, showing the  analytic continuation to the negative real axis ... is the heart of the matter, I think?  And not that gluing business, which I have never learned ... (also, this is practice for complex analysis exams, not anything more advanced, like algebraic geometry.)